# Laravel Reloading Page

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have been using laravel for quiet sometime now and i have been stuck with this issue for a while.

Whenever I call a page with an id on the end the page consistently reloads.
For example
http://localhost:8000/event/**2**

with **2** being the ID of the event

Answer (score 0):

So i have solved this problem by simpling adding a '/' to end of my url.

I am not to sure what was causing this issue but I was glad to find a work

around.